# Split a String on '\' character when '\' is followed by a character which becomes a valid escape sequence

Tags: c#

```
        public void Test(String userWithDomain)
        {   
            // assume userWithDomain could be a console input or an ajax call.

            // 1: userWithDomain = "domain\\user"; 
            // 2: userWithDomain = "domain\user"; 
            // 3: userWithDomain = "domain\test";

            // (1) would work;
            // (2) would work too [this kind of input is not valid from within a C# app]
            // (3) wouldn't work because \t would a valid escape sequence and output would be "domin" "est"

            String[] split = userWithDomain.Split(new String[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (String item in split)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            // How do I fix (3)?
        }
```

**Edit:**

The code works in all cases but fails if this method is called from javascript like Test("domain\testuser");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that it's your test data which is screwed up, rather than the code.

For example, if you're doing:

```
string userWithDomain = "domain\test";
```

then that's *not* what you'd actually get from AJAX, console input etc - because you've actually got "domain", then a tab, then "est".

To represent the text "domain\test" in C# source code, the simplest approach is to use a verbatim string literal:

```
string userWithDomain = @"domain\test";
```

Use *that* in your test case, and I suspect you'll find it works fine. (Personally I'd use `userWithDomain.Split('\\', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`, but that's a different question really.)

Comment: The code works in all cases but fails if this method is called from javascript like Test("domain\testuser"); I cannot enforce a rule to force them to escape the '\' char on js side like Test("domain\\testuser")

Comment: @Vijay Sirigiri: That's because JavaScript uses similar string escaping rules - you're passing in garbage data. You don't *actually* want to be parsing a string with a tab in, do you? If you're saying that you can't trust the JavaScript to provide you with sensible data, then it's hard to see how you can do anything on the C# side. Garbage in, garbage out...

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is something you actually can't do. As you can't "detect" wether the javascript author wanted to have a backslash followed by a t or a real tab. You'll have to rely on your javascript author to use the proper escape format when required.

If you're really sure about this (assuming the escaped characters aren't valid characters in a user name) you could just escape it again, e.g. looking for all tabs and replacing them with `@"\t"` again.